# How to SELECT data from SQL Server using .NET 2.0 -- as simple as possible

Tags: ado.net, .net-2.0, data-access

Easy question:

I have an app that needs to make a half dozen SELECT requests to SQL Server 2005 and write the results to a flat file.  That's it.

If I could use .NET 3.5, I'd create a LINQ-To-SQL model, write the LINQ expressions and be done in an hour.  What is the next best approach given that I can't use .NET 3.0 or 3.5?  Are ADO.NET DataReaders/DataSets the best option, or am I forgetting something else available?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the non-code suggestions too.  My "flat file" is actually an ESRI Shapefile (so code is needed for that part), but BCP and SSIS are good to know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the SqlCommand and SqlDataReader classes are your best bet. If you need to write the results to a flat file, you should use the reader directly instead of going to a DataSet, since the latter will load the result in memory before you're able to write it out to a flat file.

The SqlDataReader allows you to read out the data in a streaming fashion, making your app a lot more scalable for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick K so helpfully answered on my SQL Server 2000 [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/69181/what-tools-do-you-recommend-for-getting-data-out-of-sqlserver-2000-databases) on serverfault, the [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646%28SQL.80%29.aspx) is really handy for this.

You can write a batch file or quick script that call BCP with your queries and have it dump csv,sql direct to a text file!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Dave Van den Eynde's answer above, but I would say that if you're pushing a large amount of data into these files, and if your app is something that can support it, then it's worth taking a look at making an [SSIS](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/integration-services.aspx) package.

Could be complete overkill for this, but it's something that is often overlooked for bulk import/export.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could avoid writing code and use BCP.exe:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(SQL.90).aspx